# Order Statistics - simple random sampling without replacement

Tags: independence, order-statistics, sufficient-statistics, factorisation-theorem

I am studying the Watson-Royall theorem and I have a question in item 2:
"under simple random sampling, the vector of order statistics is sufficient ..."
I wish to use the factorisation theorem. I know how to do it when the data is iid, but in this case it is considered simple random sampling without replacement ...

Comment: You need only convince yourself that permuting the order statistics does not destroy any of the information available from the sample.

Comment: Is this related to the fact that we have a symmetric function in your arguments?

Comment: Ultimately, it comes down to the fact that the result of a simple random sample is an *unordered* collection of observations: it does not keep track of the sequence in which the observations were made.